# onbeforeunload with a popup, that redirects via header

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script:

```
function LinkedINAuth() {
    linkedInAuthWindow=window.open(root_url+'ajax-connect.php?social-login&auto-close&method=linkedin&auth','LinkedIN Auth','height=200,width=150');
    if (window.focus) {linkedInAuthWindow.focus()}

    linkedInAuthWindow.onbeforeunload = function(){
        CheckLinkedINUser();
    }
    return false;
}
```

If the pop-up page isnt redirected, the function `linkedInAuthWindow.onbeforeunload` works perfectly. So when I then close the window, the `CheckLinkedINUser()` function is fired.

However, when the popup has redirected the user (to i.e. LinkedIN) and I then close the popup window, the event is not fired.

For instance; if the user closes the window when LinkedIN requests for permission, I would like to track this.

Comment: A redirect means a new `window` object is created, so the handler you bound to the _old_ window instance is gone …

Comment: Is there anything I can do then? Maybe I can use the callback from LinkedIN to redirect to a URL, with a javascript code which tells the parent to reload? Because right now when the auth was successful, the popup is automaticly closed (because the page which is callbacked to from LinkedIn has window.close(); script), and then the user has to manually refresh the page, before he knows he was authed.